# Distance between paypal-button and text

Tags: html, css, paypal

on the [start page](https://www.garde-division-germany.de) I put a PayPal donation button. Above and under the button is a line of text. The distance of the button to the text above is normal. But the distance to the text under the button is too large.
I looked with FireBug on it but I'm not very good in Html and CSS and can't figure out the problem.
Can somebody tell me how to set the distances of texts and button the same?

This is the code I added to the side:

```html
<div class="top-3" style="width:50%;">
<div class="module_margin">
<div class="module_">
<div class="module">
<div class="module_padding">
<div class="module_content">
<div class="custom">
<p style="text-align: center;">Wir freuen uns über Eure Spende für die Clan-Kasse.</p>
<form target="_top" method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" name="cmd">
<input type="hidden" value="PZJ5MPQQPDYVY" name="hosted_button_id">
<input type="image" border="0" alt="Jetzt einfach, schnell und sicher online bezahlen – mit PayPal." name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/DE/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
<img width="1" height="1" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="">
</form>
<p style="text-align: center;">Vielen Dank, Eure GADIV</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks and regards,

Blubbfisch

Comment: I don't see any text above or below the button in your example.

Comment: Your body's `line-height:160%` is making the "line", which consists of the image, bigger than it needs to be. Try a more sensible `line-height`, such as `1.2`.

Comment: Isn't this just for the background?                                                                                            body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 160%;
}

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend adding something to your form so that you will be able to find it through css like a unique class , ex:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" class="paypal_form" method="post" target="_top">
```

now that you have a unique class you can identify the text and button that is in this form and you can play with `line-height` and `margin` properities.  Now since you didn't actually provide an example with text in it I can't give an exact answer , but you can start off with something like:

```
 .paypal_form input[type="image']{margin-bottom:2px;line-height:5px;}
 .paypal_form a {line-height:5px;}
```

Comment: I have added the full code with text. And I have added the class. I will try what I can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Could the whitespace in your image be the issue?

I took your snippet and added the following to show that the distance is the same, but the whitespace is different. this creates an illusion that the line spacing is off

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        p { text-align:center;}

        form {border:1px solid black;}
      </style>
</head>

<body>

    <p>line of text</p>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="************">
                <input style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/DE/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Jetzt einfach, schnell und sicher online bezahlen â€“ mit PayPal.">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>


    <p>line of text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did enter the full code with text in my post. What do you mean by whitespace?

Comment: I mean this: <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> creates whitespace. if you don't need that, perhaps you can remove it and it solves your problem.

Comment: It seems to be importent because its part of every donation button I looked at.

Comment: it's only a 1x1 pixel image, so i am not convinced it's important...however, you should ask paypal if it's necessary if you're concerned.